# Running a program from another program

Tags: c++, input

I have a C# program(call it A) that takes a photo and transforms it in a 2d array of values. I also have a c++(call it B) program that use as input that type of matrix. What I want to do is to call A by code written in B. I have no idea how to specify input for A (don't know if it's possible in any way). The only solution I found is to have a directory in which I have the photo(s) and a file that first is opened written in and closed by A when it is called and than B open it again and read it.
The question is: Is there a way to give input to a program called from another program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *many* ways to pass input from one program to another.

- Write a file in one program and read it in another.
- Create a shared memory region and store the data there (use for example [`boost::shared_memory`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html), or [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_open.html) on Posix, or [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx) on Windows.
- Write the data to stdout in one program, read from stdin in the other and pipe the two programs together.
- Create a pipe and write the data to one end of the pipe, and read from the other end.
- Have one program listen on a socket, and the other send data to it.
- More

Depending on usage, all of these *can* be appropriate, but I would stick to writing a file to start with.  It makes it much easier to separately test and debug the two programs.  Rather than using a fixed directory and filename, I would have A write to a file, and then invoke B with the name of the file on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is by using a pipeline. In terminal it would look like this:

```
programA < image | programB
```